# how to add two summed values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

Is it possible to add two summed values in mysql like the query shown below (figure 1)?

I have the query below, and I am trying to add qty and pro.

**Figure 1**

```
    SELECT  

    SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty,
    SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pro

    SUM(pro + qty)

    FROM OrderDetails;
```

I will need to use qty and pro many times throughout the query, so I don't want to write the query as shown in **figure 2**

**figure 2**

```
    SELECT  

    SUM(
    SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    + 
    SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    )

    FROM OrderDetails;
```

**EDITED**

What I mean by using **qty** and **pro** multiple times throughout the query is something like the following.

**Query Example one** - is what I am trying to do, where I can reuse qty and pro multiple times throughout the query, in places like `sum(pro + qty)` and `having (qty > 0 AND pro > 0)`, without having to rewrite the whole sum statement.

```
SELECT  

SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty,
SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pro

SUM((pro + qty)/100)

FROM OrderDetails

GROUP BY value

HAVING (
       qty > 2
       AND
       pro > 2
       )
;
```

**query example 2** - is what I have to currently do, and it seems like very poor practice to have to rewrite `SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` multiple times, rather than a simple **qty** or **pro** like in the query above

```
SELECT  

SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty,
SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pro

SUM((
     SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      +
     SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
)/100)

FROM OrderDetails

GROUP BY value

HAVING (
       SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 2
       AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 2
       )
;
```

is there no way to add `SUM(pro + qty)` after defining it once in examples like `SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty`

Comment: No it isn't possible. You might want to expand on what you mean by 'I will need to use qty and pro many times throughout the query'

Comment: You can't use aliases in the `SELECT` clause, only in the `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can compute using the below query.

```
SELECT  

SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty,
SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pro,
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1
        WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END) AS qtyProSum
FROM OrderDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create View for the below query and use it any of times

```
SELECT  
    SUM(CASE WHEN value > 0 AND xp = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty,
    SUM(CASE WHEN value > 1 AND xp = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pro
    FROM OrderDetails;
```